# Jquery mobile - how to specify that a link should be ajax-ed with POST

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a regular link
`<a href="Auth/LogOut" data-role="button">Log Out<a>`and I have to specify that it should be navigated to with the POST verb.

How exactly do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Docs: [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/methods.html)

---

```
// using changePage to use POST on submit
$("#LogOut").bind("submit", function() {
  if (validateFormData()) {
    changePage({
      url: "Auth/LogOut",
      type: "post",
      data: anyDataNeedingPassing
    }, false);
```

Comment: From my understanding jQM will handle the event.

Comment: What do you mean it will handle the event? Clicking on the button has to trigger the code you posted somehow. What is the markup for this code sample?

Comment: You are right. I did some digging around in my books and came across this. Let me know if it works for you.